# Group comparison for small sample with repeated measured data

Tags: small-sample, group-differences, resampling

I have very small dataset.

When I conducted rank sum test between the groups (A vs B; A vs C), I found no significant results, but just trends level difference.

Is there any alternative statistical methods? (Resampling methods??)

I used R and Stata, but I'm not familiar with resampling methods such as bootstrapping.

One more thing. Each subject has several repeated measured data. Can I simply compare this to a group? What do I do if this is mixed-effect data.

- Group A: subject1 (1077, 984, 1074, 1370), subject2 (955, 1094, 863, 879), subject3 (1354, 963, 944, 944)
- Group B: subject4 (1206, 1123, 1177, 975), subject5 (1020, 2037, 1073, 1101)
- Group C: subject6 (1311, 1378, 1274, 1025), subject7 (1847, 2144, 1151, 889), subject8 (1165, 948, 953, 994)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I am correct you are conducting [the Mann-Whitney U test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mann%E2%80%93Whitney_U_test), a non-parametric rank sum test. This is similar to a t-test, but does not require the normal distributions that the t-test assume.

With very small sample sizes, you are only likely to detect a significant effect if the effect is very large. You're right in thinking you should be incorporating the repeated measurement observations you obtained. That will provide more information, thus increasing the odds of detecting a smaller effect.

If you truly should be using a non-parametric test (I dont have the information necessary to determine this), one option is the [Friedman test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Friedman_test). This test can include 2 > measurement occasions and is non-parametric.

The syntax in R is quite straight forward:

```
RoundingTimes <-
  matrix(c(5.40, 5.50, 5.55,
           5.85, 5.70, 5.75,
           5.20, 5.60, 5.50,
           5.55, 5.50, 5.40,
           5.90, 5.85, 5.70,
           5.45, 5.55, 5.60,
           5.40, 5.40, 5.35,
           5.45, 5.50, 5.35,
           5.25, 5.15, 5.00,
           5.85, 5.80, 5.70,
           5.25, 5.20, 5.10,
           5.65, 5.55, 5.45,
           5.60, 5.35, 5.45,
           5.05, 5.00, 4.95,
           5.50, 5.50, 5.40,
           5.45, 5.55, 5.50,
           5.55, 5.55, 5.35,
           5.45, 5.50, 5.55,
           5.50, 5.45, 5.25,
           5.65, 5.60, 5.40,
           5.70, 5.65, 5.55,
           6.30, 6.30, 6.25),
         nrow = 22,
         byrow = TRUE,
         dimnames = list(1 : 22,
                         c("Round Out", "Narrow Angle", "Wide Angle")))
friedman.test(RoundingTimes)

wb <- aggregate(warpbreaks$breaks,
            by = list(w = warpbreaks$wool,
                          t = warpbreaks$tension),
                FUN = mean)

friedman.test(x ~ w | t, data = wb)
```

Where `x` is a dependent variable, `w` is a grouping factor, and `t` is a catagorical vector indicating the measurement occasion.

Note, this example is taken from the [friedman.test() manual](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/stats/html/friedman.test.html).

Edit:

Bootstrapping is a re-sampling process to obtain Standard Errors. Bootstrapping is frequently used when direct methods cannot be used to solve the likelihood function and derive SEs. Bootstrapping is quite simple. The data set is sampled with replacement, thus resulting in a new data set that could have multiples of the same observation. An analysis is conducted on this new data set and estimates are retained. This process is done K, times. K being a user specified value. After the K iterations a sampling distribution is generated from the retained parameter estimates. This distribution is then used to compute bootstrapped standard errors.

I do not think bootstrapping is appropriate in your case. With such low sample sizes, the resulting distributions will never approximate normality. Thus traditional methods which assume normally distributed residuals should not be used.

Comment: "That will provide more information, thus increasing the odds of detecting a smaller effect.". Could you try OP's data to perform one-way ANOVA (ignore the repeated measurement) and fit a mixed linear model to incorporate the repeated measurement to see the difference?

Comment: That could be done, in theory. But it just wont provide any meaningful information. The sample size is so low, imagine estimating a slope for, say group B at time 1. That is simply 2 points. Yes, you can draw a straight line between 2 points. However, any estimate you receive from that slope will be very unstable. Probably safer to stick with the Friedman test.

Comment: In fact, I mean where did you get "That will provide more information, thus increasing the odds of detecting a smaller effect."

Comment: Dear Roman numerals, Thanks for your answer. But, I still don't know what is the difference between the nonparametric test such as Friedman or Mann Whitney test AND resampling such as bootstrapping or permutation test??

Comment: I updated my response to answer your question. You should probably stick with the Friedman test. Or simply use graphs to describe your data, the sample size is just too low to provide any confidence in an estimate.